# NavigationLink in SwiftUI not working anymore

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I´m creating an App and use `NavigationLink` in Swift/SwiftUI, but it doesn't work anymore. I don't now since when, but 2 or 3 weeks ago, all working fine. The `NavigationLinks` which already are in the code for longer, working fine. But today I've used new ones, and they don´t work. It looks in the Simulator and on a real device, if they are disabled or something. They are grey and you can't click on them or if you clicked on them, nothing happens. Is there any solution?

```
import SwiftUI

struct MedikamenteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ASSView(),
                label: {
                    Text("ASS")
                })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: AdrenalinView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Adrenalin")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct MedikamenteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MedikamenteView()
    }
}
```

And for example, this one is working fine:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RechtView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
           NavigationLink(
            destination: ParagraphenView(),
            label: {
                Text("Paragraphen")
            })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: AufklaerungEinwilligungView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Die Aufklärung mit nachfolgender Einwilligung")
                })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: NotSanGView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Wichtiges aus dem NotSanG")
                })
        }
        .navigationTitle("Recht")
    }
}

struct RechtView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RechtView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have navigationLink inside NavigationView. I tested by adding inside NavigationView and it’s working, else it’s disabled as you mentioned.

Comment: If I add a NavigationView it is working, you're right. But since when I have to add this? In my other code example is no NavigationView and it is working nevertheless

Comment: What does the parent view of `RechtView` look like? If it contains a `NavigationView` then `RechtView` is within a `NavigationView` and your links will work. If you trace back up the view hierarchy, I'm sure you will find a `NavigationView` somewhere and that'll be the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from the comments that you've found out it will only work in a `NavigationView` and are now wondering why. It only matters that your view is embedded in a `NavigationView` directly above it the View hierarchy. For example, this code would work:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           NavigationLink(label: "Go to next view", destination: NextView())
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
...
```

While this won't:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var modalPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Show fullscreen cover"){
                modalPresented = true
            }
        }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $modalPresented, content: SecondView())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(label: "Go to next view", destination: NextView())
        // Doesn't work because the view is in a fullScreenCover and therefore not a part of the NavigationView.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and you're right, in my other example there is a NavigationView in hierarchy above.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use **NavigationLinks** inside `NavigationView{}`.
Without it **NavigationLink** wont work.
Try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MedikamenteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ASSView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("ASS")
                    })
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: AdrenalinView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Adrenalin")
                    })
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct MedikamenteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MedikamenteView()
    }
}
```

Your second code sample might be loaded from previous view which has used `NavigationView {}`

Comment: You're right, thank you! It solved my problem and you're right, in the second example is a NavigationView in previous view. It was my bad yesterday.

Comment: hilariously i made this mistake today

Answer (score 0):

this code seems to show no error but does not work. when i press the text, i cannot change views. i have tried everything, copied code from the swift documentation, coped code from different forums, but it does not work at all !

```
import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            NavigationLink{
                LinearAlgebra()
            }label: {
                Text("hi")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(
                        destination: LinearAlgebra(),
                        label: {
                            Text("linearA")
                        })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Content()
    }
}
```

[this is what the output window shows, the links don't light up, pressing them does not do anything!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Evzk.png)